# Transferring data to modal in Angular 11?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, datatable

I have a data table on an html page that is populated by an array of objects. In each row is a delete button. When you click the delete button, a modal pops up asking if you really want to delete that row.

I'm trying to figure out how to transfer the id of the row into the modal so that when someone clicks "yes", then I can send that id to an endpoint that would delete that entry from the table.

Keep in mind that the code for the modal is on the same page as the code for the table. In other words, the modal is not a separate component.

Here is the code below and the screenshots to illustrate the issue...

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped mt-3">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Application</th>
              <th scope="col">Error Source</th>
              <th scope="col">Message</th>
              <th scope="col">StackTrace</th>
              <th scope="col">Date</th>
              <th scope="col">User</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let error of listOfErrors | paginate: { itemsPerPage: itemsPerPage, currentPage: page }">
              <td>{{ error.application }}</td>
              <td>{{ error.errorSource }}</td>
              <td>{{ error.message }}</td>
              <td>{{ error.stackTrace }}</td>
              <td>{{ error.date }}</td>
              <td>{{ error.user }}</td>
              <td class="edit-button">
                <button class="btn btn-primary"
                        type="button"                        
                        data-bs-toggle="modal"
                        attr.data-bs-target="#{{ deleteRoleModalId }}">
                  Delete
                </button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

Here is the code for the modal (again, on the same html page)

```
<app-modal [id]="deleteRoleModalId"
               [title]="deleteRoleTitle">
      <p>Are you sure you want to delete this role? </p>

      <div class="mt-3">
        <button class="btn btn-primary float-start"
                type="button"              
                (click)="deleteRole()">
          Yes
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary me-1 float-start"
                type="button"               
                data-bs-dismiss="modal">
          No
        </button>
      </div>
    </app-modal>
```

This is what the array of objects looks like...

```
public listOfErrors: any[] = [
    {
      id: 1,
      application: "Default Case Set",
      errorSource: "CASEWORK",
      message: 34,
      stackTrace: 0,
      date: 0,
      user: 0
    }
  ];
```

This is what the table looks like...

[image: data table]

This is what the modal looks like...

[image: modal]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey, could you just maybe quick create a StackBlitz or something to be able to see all the parts of your app live? This only have to contain the relevant parts of course. That costs you maybe 10 minutes but provides us a really easy way to help you. Thanks.

Comment: I'd rather just know what's causing that error I posted above.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the modal component is a child component from the main component (since you mention they are in the same HTML file),
the id is passed from the parent component to the modal via @Input(), then you can pass data to the parent (deleted/not deleted) via an eventEmitter and the @Output() decorator.

See here in the official documentation how this is exactly implemented:
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Another alternative could be using services and observables which is another viable approach albeit a bit more complex to handle information communication between components. This approach is especially useful when components are not related.

Answer (score 0):

I would create the modal as its own component and use the angular modal directive. This way you could also, be enriching this component, make it useful for any kind of deletion. In other words this component can be responsible for deleting stuff.

```
export class DeleteModalComponent {

    @ViewChild('modal', { static: true }) modal: ModalDirective;

  public deleteId= '';
    
  show(id: string): void {
        this.deleteId = id
        this.modal.show();
    }

  delete(): void {
  //Delete logic here with this.deleteId
  }

 close(): void {
        this.modal.hide();
    }
}
```

So in your table component ts file you would call the "show" method of the modal to open it, along with the rowId (errorId?).

```
/// Add the modal as a viewchild to your table component

     @ViewChild('deleteModal', { static: true }) deleteModal: DeleteModalComponent;

     openDeleteModal(rowId: string): void {
            this.deleteModal.show(rowId);
        }
```

As such in the HTML:

```
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped mt-3">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">Application</th>
                  <th scope="col">Error Source</th>
                  <th scope="col">Message</th>
                  <th scope="col">StackTrace</th>
                  <th scope="col">Date</th>
                  <th scope="col">User</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let error of listOfErrors | paginate: { itemsPerPage: itemsPerPage, currentPage: page }">
                  <td>{{ error.application }}</td>
                  <td>{{ error.errorSource }}</td>
                  <td>{{ error.message }}</td>
                  <td>{{ error.stackTrace }}</td>
                  <td>{{ error.date }}</td>
                  <td>{{ error.user }}</td>
                  <td class="edit-button">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary"
                            type="button"                        
                            data-bs-toggle="modal"
                            (click)="openDeleteModal(error.id)"
                      Delete
                    </button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>

   <deleteModal #deleteModal></deleteModal>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I put your suggested code in my application and I'm getting two errors. I put them in the original post above. Please take a look at these errors and tell me what I'm doing wrong! Thanks!!!

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. You need to install this package for the ModalDirective to work. [link]https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-bootstrap.

import { ModalDirective } from "ngx-bootstrap/modal";

Im sorry for not clarifying that part!

You should also change the "Selector" name of the Modal from "app-modal" to "deleteModal"

Comment: Please let me now if that worked :)

Comment: It didn't work! I added a third screenshot to show the errors that I'm getting, They are... 1) '"c:/users/fausta/source/repos/drifterhelix/DrifterHelix.Web/client/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDef'. 

and... 

2) (TS) Property 'deleteModal' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

Comment: Hm okay, thats basically how I've done it before. But the docs for ngx-bootstrap/modal are very good. So take a look here and I'm sure you will get it to work!

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/components/modals?tab=overview